# Running zombienet with release > polkadot v1.0.0

Tags: zombienet

I'm unable to spawn a zombienetwork with binaries > `polkadot v1.0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `polkadot v1.0.0` you not only need the `polkadot` binary but also the `polkadot-execute-worker` and `polkadot-prepare-worker` binaries. If you put them in the same folder as the `polkadot` binary it should work!